# ColdFusion 10 on Windows 2008 R2 won't start automatically after Windows Update

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update, coldfusion, startup

I'm running ColdFusion 10 Update 13 on Windows 2008 R2 x64, and since a Windows Update was applied yesterday, ColdFusion won't start automatically when Windows starts. It looks like the Windows Update was for the following:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-based Systems (KB2858725)
```

My only workaround is to set the startup type for ColdFusion to 'Automatic (Delayed Start)', but the delay is painfully long after Windows starts.

Anyone else experience this problem? Any way to solve it?

I also filed a bug here, but Adobe is usually really slow to respond, so I'm hoping the community can help:

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3713706

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen the same thing - the service doesn't start on boot properly.  I haven't spent a lot of time trying to get it working right, as Puppet covers for Adobe in my case (our config for those nodes enforces that the service is running).

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about Puppet?  How does it enforce that the service is running?

Comment: There's just a `service` [resource](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html) that managed the CF10 application service with `ensure => running`, so when the puppet agent runs (at boot up and then every half hour) it will start the service if it's not already running.  Puppet would probably be overkill for just making the service start at boot - we have it installing and managing the whole IIS and coldfusion stack and code deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try with Windows 2008 R2. I updated the .Net Framework to 4.5.1 (4.5.50938) on my Windows 7 and it works as expected. The CF10 service is set to "Automatic" start up. You may have to check the Event Viewer logs for more details.

Comment: I've also have Windows 7 with .Net Framework 4.5.1 and ColdFusion 10 automatically starts up fine.  I don't know what it is about the Windows 2008 server.  It might not have anything to do with .Net, but something happened recently that caused this problem.  How frustrating.  I've listed my event viewer logs in the bug that I filed (https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3713706), but I don't really understand the cryptic error messages.

Comment: We tried with Windows Server® 2008 Standard (6.0, Build 6001) Service Pack 1, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz (2 CPUs) and are unable to reproduce the issue. I have updated the bug as well. The Event viewer logs are very generic. You may try running CF10 service from command prompt and see, if you get anything logged there.